# I want to send a magnet using transmission-remote in window

Tags: python, linux, torrent, transmission, transmission-daemon

You could start downloading remotely from linux to
http://localhost:9091/transmission/web/
using the command in

**transmission-remote 9091-nid:password -a {magnet}.**

I want to do this on Windows as well.

I used Python and now installed transmission and daemon for window and confirmed that it works on the web.
But I don't know how to send a magnet.

Comment: The `-a` option is for passing torrent files or urls, not magnet links.